# Collusion not working on object

Tags: physics, collision

I am doing [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IxcR_s3_VMs&t=139s)

And I have added a collision to the outer object but the inflating ball inside still wont collide with the grid on the outside? Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know Soft Body enough, are you sure that they can handle this kind of interaction with a collision object?